# Insert formula using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The below vba code fails to insert the formula into the cell. Cell E3 contains 25,208.70 - 15,685.60.
Expected outcome is  25,208.70.
I do get the expected answer if the formula is inserted into the cell BJ3 but fails to insert the formula using
VBA.

Please help!

```
Range("BJ3").Formula = "=VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(E3, FIND(" - ", E3) - 1)))"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try:

```
Range("BJ3").Formula = "=VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(E3, FIND("" - "", E3) - 1)))"
```

Comment: @Maciej Los: I am afraid that Excel formulas do not accept anything else but double quotes to define a string. It accepts  simple quotes only in between double quotes, in order to correctly retrieve the Sheet name (for instance) in case it contains spaces...

Comment: I have a similar problem given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373706/insert-formula-using-vba-dynamically

Comment: Your help required_________https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64170959/vba-chart-resize-dynamic-data-for-chart-not-working

Comment: @Math Inquiry: I asked you something (there) but no any answer...