# Insert formula using VBA Dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

The below VBA code is not inserting the code for dynamic formula.

```vb
sh.Range("bj" & 2 * i + 1).FormulaLocal = "=VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(E" & 2 * i + 1 & ", FIND("" - "",  E " & 
      2 * i + 1 & ") - 1)))"""
```

Comment: Remove the trailing quote and the space after the `E`.

Comment: no it doest work

Comment: `FormulaLocal`???? You better check if that's what you really want.

Comment: Yes it does. But if your Excel is not localised to English, you will also need to change `FormulaLocal` to `Formula`, which is a [good idea anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251099/11683).

Comment: First assemble the formula as a string and check if that string is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try:

```
sh.Range("bj" & 2 * i + 1).FormulaLocal = "=VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(E" & 2 * i + 1 & ", FIND("" - "",  E" & 2 * i + 1 & ") - 1)))"
```

But do you have a function inside the above formula to be localized according to your language settings?

Comment: @Math Inquiry: Does the VBA code write the formula?  I mean, does it look being correct? In your code, an extra `"` was added...

Comment: I just gave it a try, since Formula failed

Comment: @Math Inquiry: But, it may fail if the formula **result** will be an error... Try please: `Debug.Print "=VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(E" & 2 * i + 1 & ", FIND("" - "",  E " & 2 * i + 1 & ") - 1)))"`. Does it return what you want in  Immediate Window? If yes, you have to check if the targeted cell contains the value you suppose it to contain...

Comment: Its resolved , immediate window showed a space after E, it was removed and works fine.

Comment: I already corrected the above code. I also observed it... :)

Comment: Yes,  i missed it :)

Comment: @Math Inquiry: Don't worry... Me, too, initially... :) I only was trying to correct the formula **string**. Only after you said it does not work I also checked the formula itself...

Comment: Oh , that's motivating,Thanks